# Embed Image in HTML String Email Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

Hello I wanted to embed an Image in a Mail in Laravel.
Sure when using a link to the public resource for my image, it does work but I dont know if it is better than embedding the Image directly into the Email itself.

I dont use Markdown nor Email Templates.

My common occurring function looks like:

```php
Mail::send([], [], function ($msg) use ($user, $content, $mail) {
                    $msg->to($user->mail);
                    $msg->subject($mail->title);
                    $msg->setBody($this->generateHtmlEmail($content, $user), 'text/html');
                });
```

When using a base64 encoded string for my image as source, it doesnt get displayed in clients such as Gmail etc.

I know there is a function like: `$message->embed(path)` but I dont know, how to implement it in my function since I use a html string as the body content

Comment: On the view you can put: `<img src="{{ $message->embedData($data, 'example-image.jpg') }}">` like the [docs code](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#inline-attachments)

Comment: Well, I don't use a view, I am using html strings. I mentioned it in the question